# Date Range CUBESET function giving an #N/A error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot, datamodel

I've been using this CUBESET function without issue for a couple of weeks to calculate a sum between two dates, but today it's giving me an #N/A error:

=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Hours]]","[AllWork].[Group].[GrpOne]","[History].[CurrentlyActive].[Active]",CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[AllWork].[Date].&["&TEXT(PrevWk_Start,"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss")&"]:[AllWork].[Date].&["&TEXT(PrevWk_End,"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss")&"]"))

There are no errors in any underlying data that I can find.  The only thing I can think of is that there are no dates in the CUBESET that match PrevWk_End (which is April 3, 2021 in this case - all the other dates involved are available).  What do I need to do to overcome this error now and going forward?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm now sure it has to do with the fact that the value for PrevWk_End doesn't exist in the available dates.  I used the day before PrevWk_End (which does exist) and the formula worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

= CUBEVALUE ("ThisWorkbookDataModel", "[Measures]. [Hours]]", "[AllWork]. [Group]. [GrpOne]", "[History]. [PresentActive]. [Active]", CUBESET ("ThisWorkbookDataModel "," [AllWork]. [Date]. & ["& TEXT (PrevWk_Start," YYYY-MM-DDThh: mm: ss ") &"]: [OTSandWD_Table]. [Date]. & ["& TEXT (PrevWk_End," ปปปป - ดด - วว: mm: ss ") &"] "))

Comment: This looks like the original formula, but with spaces added.  I tried it, however, but the error remained.